# Directory/files owned by a non-existent user

Tags: linux, security, users, directory

A user has created a directory with files, but the user does not exist in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group`. The system is a Fedora server with an FTP server and proxy which redirects to a CentOS server with Apache where the directory was created. Where could the user have come from? Is this a security problem?

Comment: Is it possible at all that the user has been removed? What happens to the files belonging to him in that case?

Comment: With `ls -l` I can see his entries. I don't know if it has been removed. If then he has root access... But good question. Is the passwd the single place where such a user can be put in? Or can with a security hole user-rights written without ever an existing user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Other possibilities which don't involve security breach:

- If root extracts some files from a tar, `tar` will create that files with uid/gid of *source* system even if that user/group does not exist on *destination* host.
- If root uses `rsync -a` to synchronize directory on two differents systems, `rsync` will create that files with uid/gid of *source* system even if that user/group does not exist on *destination* host.

A lot of file transfer activities, between hosts that have not the same user list, can create this kind of *unknown owner* files.

Comment: The directory has been created from a tar file. The owner of the tar file is root. So the question now is, how the tar file came on the server. The normal ftp log files doesn't mention something. Either its the apache or a CMS.

Comment: IMHO, this is **another question**. You can start reading these response on "server fault": [How do I know if my Linux server has been hacked?](http://serverfault.com/questions/2783/how-do-i-know-if-my-linux-server-has-been-hacked) and [How can I detect unwanted intrusions on my servers?](http://serverfault.com/questions/650/how-can-i-detect-unwanted-intrusions-on-my-servers).

Comment: Another couple of reasons to *never* work as root.

Comment: Or root simply downloaded the file, with wget or ftp (client) or similar, none of which makes logs. After all, root had to extract it, whether this was done with a shell or part of a CMS. Do you (or whoever else legitimately has root) not remember doing such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

Two obvious possibilities which don't involve security breach:

- exported file system (NFS, samba, ...) to a computer which has such account
- network wide identification (NIS, ldap, ...) which allows such account

Comment: I also thought that. But `showmount` tells me too much results. So I need another way to narrow the cause for the security breach.